# Trying to save an attachment from outlook via pythonCOM

Tags: python, com, outlook, save, attachment

I am going through my outlook mail to fetch all attachments and save them in my computer.

This is my code:

```
import win32com.client
import os, sys

class OutlookLib:

    def __init__(self, settings={}):
        self.settings = settings

    # Gets all messages in outlook   
    def get_messages(self):      
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

        # This allows us to access the "folder" hierarchy accessible within
        # Outlook. You can see this hierarchy yourself by opening Outlook
        # manually and bringing up the folder menu
        # (which typically says "Inbox" or "Outlook Today" or something).
        ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        all_inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items
        return all_inbox

    def get_body(self, msg):
        return msg.Body

    def get_subject(self, msg):
        return msg.Subject

    def get_sender(self, msg):
        return msg.SenderName

    def get_recipient(self, msg):
        return msg.To

    def get_attachments(self, msg):
        return msg.Attachments

# Gets an attachment
# Return true if clean
# Otherwise, return false
def checkAttach(fileAtt):
    pass # TODO something here

def Main():
    global attach

    outlook = OutlookLib()
    messages = outlook.get_messages()

    # Loop all messages
    msg = messages.GetFirst()
    while msg:
        #print msg.Subject
        if not len(msg.Attachments) is 0:
            attach.append((msg.Attachments, msg.Subject))
        msg = messages.GetNext()

    for attachTuple in attach:
        print "Checking attachments under " + attachTuple[1]
        for fileAtt in attachTuple[0]:
            fileAtt.SaveAsFile(r"C:\Users\Lidor\Desktop\Dina\scan-mail")
            if checkAttach(fileAtt):
                print fileAtt.FileName + " was found as malicous."

attach = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Now this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lidor\Desktop\Dina\scan-mail\mailScanner.py", line 67, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:\Users\Lidor\Desktop\Dina\scan-mail\mailScanner.py", line 60, in Main
    fileAtt.SaveAsFile(r"C:\Users\Lidor\Desktop")
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in SaveAsFile
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u"Cannot save the attachment. You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.", None, 0, -2147024891), None)
```

This is weird because I am admin and I have permissions on the pst and the output folder.
I have also tried to run it in a admin CMD and still got the same error.

btw if you know of a way to get the attachment into a python file object instead of saving it to my computer it will be even better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must specify the full attachment file name including the name part.
You are only specifying the directory name, you need to concatenate the directory and file names:

```
fileAtt.SaveAsFile(r"C:\Users\Lidor\Desktop\Dina\scan-mail\" + fileAtt.FileName)
```

Comment: I got the same error using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in C# and this solution worked there too!!  Thanks so much.